# How do I use a lua_topointer when grabbing a closure from the stack?

Tags: c, lua, nim-lang

So I've been trying to implement lua inside of nim using the C bindings and everything works fine except I don't know how to deal with lua functions being passed to my nim/c created procs/functions.

Lua code:

```
task("custom_task", function()
    task("This is called from lua")
end)
```

Nim proc:

```
proc task*(state: lua.Pstate): cint {.cdecl.} =

  var task_name : cstring

  if lua.isstring(state, 1) == 1:
    task_name = lua.tostring(state, cint(1))

  if task_name != nil:
    echo task_name

  # this is triggered for the 2nd parameter
  if lua.isfunction(state, 2) == true:
    var test = lua.topointer(state, 2)

  result = 1
```

So the lua api doesn't have a `tofunction` method, just a `tocfunction`, so it seems like the only way to grab that function is using topointer, but I can't figure out how to use it in nim. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The second argument is a Lua function.  It is not convertible to C function.  It should be invoked by means of Lua C API when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by `lua_topointer` is not intended to be used for anything but hasing or output/debugging.  Citing the [Lua manual](https://lua.org/manual/5.3/index.html#lua_topointer):

> There is no way to convert the pointer back to its original value.
>
> Typically this function is used only for hashing and debug information.

So if you want to work with a lua function, you'll have to find a different way.  My suggestion would be to store the function in the lua registry. The function can then be identified by the registry index and its lua_State.

The only problem with this approach is that you'll have to remember to remove the function from the registry.  Otherwise it will never be garbage collected.

Alternatively, one could `lua_dump` the function, which is obviously a rather expensive operation.

Comment: Side note: You might be interested in [hslua](https://github.com/hslua/hslua), a library providing Haskell bindings to Lua.  I guess many problems nim coders might face will be similar to those faced by Haskells. I'm the current maintainer, feel free to shoot me a mail if you have questions.